# How to display api data on children column in ag grid angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to call the `fieldName` in children or how to display.

here's the code.

***list.component.ts***

```
      monthNames = new Array(
    ['January'], ['February'], ['March'],
    ['April'], ['May'], ['June'],
    ['July'], ['August'], ['September'],
    ['October'], ['November'], ['December'],
  );

 ngOnInit() {
    this.setColumnHeader();
  }

setColumnHeader() {
       this.globals.getData('/users').pipe(take(1)).subscribe((data: any) => {
              const record = data['data'];
              record.map((x: any) => {
                this.rowData.push({
                  'fieldName': x.firstName,
                  'lastName': x.lastName
                });
              });
            });

            for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
              this.columnDefs.push({
                'headerName': this.monthNames[i],
                'field': this.monthNames[i],
                'width': 100,
               ///child
                'children': [
                  {
                    'headerName': 'Total', 'columnGroupShow': 'closed', 'field': 'total',
                    'valueGetter': function (params: any) {
                      return params.data.sample + params.data.sampleb;
                    }
                  },
                  {
                      'headerName': 'a', 'editable': true, 'columnGroupShow': 'open', 'field': 'sample',
                      'valueParser': this.numberParser
                  },
           ////////call the fieldName
                 {
                    ///here 

                    ///the 'headerName' should be the fieldName
                  }

          });
        }
      }
}
 numberParser(params: any) {
    return Number(params.newValue);
  }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you can add more description for what you ask for, example: JSON(data), your first try or something else.

Comment: for the ```this.columnDefs.push``` it display only the month january to december. then example month of ```january``` have child which is ```total and a``` then I'm trying to push a new column & row which is under the ```this.global``` and now I'm trying to get the value of ```fieldName```

Comment: yeah, that will help other to understand what you want, you can start by declare monthNames, numberParser and what you expect inside the columnDefs.

Comment: done updating the code to understand what is the value of monthNames

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you really want, but here you can try this.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
  const data = {
    'headerName': this.monthNames[i],
    'field': this.monthNames[i],
    'width': 100,
    ///child
    'children': [
      {
        'headerName': 'Total', 'columnGroupShow': 'closed', 'field': 'total',
        'valueGetter': function (params: any) {
          return params.data.sample + params.data.sampleb;
        }
      },
      {
        'headerName': 'a', 'editable': true, 'columnGroupShow': 'open', 'field': 'sample',
        'valueParser': this.numberParser
      },
    ]
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < this.rowData.length; j++) {

    data.children.push(
      {
        'headerName': this.rowData[j].fieldName, 'editable': true, 'columnGroupShow': 'open', 'field': 'sample',
        'valueParser': this.rowData[j].lastName
      }
    )
  }
  this.columnDefs.push(data)
}
```

you can comment if this not what you expect, hope that help.

Comment: it should not be the same on the other column

Comment: the child should not be the same on the other child